# Microsoft teams custom tab, sending notification to user's activity feed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-teams

I'm designing a custom team tab using React that needs to send notifications to the users' activity feed. What is the best way to achieve this?
I'm aware of the existence of [proactive messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging), is it the only way to do it? If it is, a pointer on how to implement it to a custom tab would be appreciated.
Or is there a better method to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think proactive messaging would be the best way. It means your app will need to feature a bot as well as the tab. To be clear, it's not your "tab" per se that would implement the messaging, rather your tab would call your backend/api, which would sent the proactive message via the bot to the notification feed. Regarding implementing it, give it a try first and post on this site if you have any questions/run into any trouble. (As a totally terrible plug, I'll be discussing proactive messaging later today, if you're interested, in a session at the TeamsDayOnline free event - see [here](https://www.teamsdayonline.com/) for details).

Comment: Proactive messaging it is then, thank you for your answer. I'll see if I can attend your session, which session will you be filling on?

Comment: great, catch you later. I'm giving "Real-World Lessons for Building Teams Apps"

Comment: I watched your session btw, great session @HiltonGiesenow. I don't think I have any question for now as I feel that I need to dip my toes on actually making the bot first. Probably will post another question if I ran into any issues.

Comment: Thanks - glad you found it worthwhile!

Comment: oh, please go ahead and upvote or mark as answer, so others can see this answer was helpful

Comment: Hey Hilton, sorry to bother you again. I've finally got around to work on my bot. What I backend service/API would I need to send request from my tab to the bot. I'm not very versed in backend programming, any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: So in terms of code/platform, you've got various options, but ideally stick with one that's got more support/example in the area (best are C# or node.js). There are various docs and samples on the net for that (you can search for 'Teams Proactive Messaging' for example, or search on this site under my profile, I've answered questions on it frequently). There are also samples in the Bot Framework Sample project on GitHub from MS. (out of space...)

Comment: In terms of how to host and then invoke your code (your C# or Node), you'd want that 'proactive' code to be something you can invoke from your tab, like basically an API. For that, the easiest is to use something like an Azure Function project. Select C# or Node.js from the list of templates, pop in your Proactive code, and you'll have an https://... endpoint you can call from your tab

Comment: that's a very very high level overview, but hopefully gives you some good starting points

Comment: Thank you very much, although it is high level, it is exactly what I'm looking for. I'll mess around and will probably bother you again if I got into a stump.

Comment: glad to help. If you do get stuck with anything, raise it as a new question though, so others can help if I can't